# Nodejs Express handlebars how to include .hbs inside another .hbs without templates

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

How could I include .hbs inside another .hbs without templates? I'm using a component based architecture for Nodejs wih Express and I need to include hbs files  with  content for use the `{{values}}` in both, html and js sides without duplicating anything and clean.

I tried using partialsDir like this:

```
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
    defaultLayout: 'layout',
    extname: '.hbs',
    layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname),
    partialsDir: [
        path.join(__dirname, 'dashboard', '_public', 'main'),
        path.join(__dirname, 'home', '_public', 'main')
    ]
}));
```

but it gets all of the scripts of all of the views of all of the routes. And using `{{>viewScript}}` (templates) it load all the .hbs (when I go to home I have the home partial .hbs, when I go to dashboard I have the home and the dashboard partials .hbs so that not works for me.

I tried with src, but it doesn't work (mime error)

```
<script src="viewScript.hbs"></script>
```

I can combine both .hbs with its own js inside one .hbs file, ok, but I wanted to keep those pieces separated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a clean solution for this case to get those pieces on separate files (more simple than any kind of complex template system when you have the views in components instead of having all views on an single path).

In .hbs could be a small dictionary before loading the script with all string values I could need.

```
<script>
    var hello = "{{{lang.hello}}}";
</script>
<script src="viewScript.js"></script>
```

this method is simple, don't duplicate anything and leaves me to do dynamic names with jquery and a lot of more stuff.